# Sending data from raspberry

Tags: python, android, sensors

im trying to make a raspberry pi based, in sea station that will measure temperature, conductivity and dissolved oxygen. I need some guidance with the whole project. I can see the measurements on Rpi but i also want to create an android app that will display those values.I use raspberry pi 4b and sim7600 for data connectivity.

Comment: Please post anything you have tried so far.

Comment: I have all the sensors attached on pi and i can read the data with a python script. So i want to view these data on my android phone with a very simple visualizing app.

Comment: please post all code  and attempts directly in the question. Press 'Edit'.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data between devices via **Socket Communication**. You can choose if you want to connect via the local IP address or the public IP address. You send bytes over the network 01001001 01000110. Socket Communication is very standardized so you can send data between different programming languages. If you want to send data over different programming languages, then I recommend sending a JSON file over the Socket communication.

Here is a video about Sockets in Python: https://youtu.be/3QiPPX-KeSc

NOTE: I had to turn my Network profile to "Private" on my devices to make them discoverable on the network. [image: Image of Network profile]

Comment: I prefer to check the values even if i am connected to different networks

Comment: It also works with connecting devices on different networks. Then you have to use your public IP address to connect.

Comment: Can you give me details and be more specific cause its my first project and im not familiar with Iot

Comment: I added a tutorial link that helped me to send data between devices on my local network.